# shared drive cannot run .exe file while using windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a application called MARN.EXE which stores in a shared drive and works fine on our Windows XP system. 
However since we use Windows7, we cannot run this EXE file. error is 
Can't run 16-bit Windows program
Cannot find file {filepath\MARN.EXE} (or one of it's components). Check to ensure the path and filename are correct and that all required libraries are available.

I'm sure I have the Full Control to that shared drive folder.
and if I copy this folder to my local laptop, it runs fine. So seems not Windows7 problem.
Does anyone know what's the issue? Thank you.

(In properties
Target: "X:\Cusdfhr Cweihe\CS 1 Svc100\Psqw\MARN.EXE" PDAS.MDB
Start in: "X:\Cusdfhr Cweihe\CS 1 Svc100\Psqw"
)

Comment: Windows 7 does not support 16-bit applications. There is no DOS subsystem available to do so. If you want to run a 16-bit app, you need to use XP (or at least have a licensed copy of Win7 Pro or higher that allows XP Virtual Mode and run your app in that instead).

Comment: Hi Ken, as I said, if I copy this shard folder into my local machine, I'm able to run this program, so it seems not the 16-bit problem. and I'm using Win7 Pro.

Comment: Are you running from a mapped drive (`x:\ `) or a UNC path (`\\server\share\ `)?

Comment: Hi Gabe, Im running from a mapped drive (x:\)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the path. Old 16-bit programs actually run on Win7 BUT there are some restrictions to the folder names. Removing spaces, dashes, etc. should do the trick. Just replace whitespaces with _ and don't use long folder names.

Comment: Hi, I only have the Full permission of folder "Psqw", so I'm unable to delete the space of the folder names, do you have other suggestions? Thank you.